# Kusto Query to the earliest timestamp grouped by user_Id

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, appinsights

I'm just starting with kusto, and my journey was abruptly stopped by the problem of getting the list of user_Ids with the timestamp of the very first customEvent sent by a user in the given time frame.

How should I modify my query to get the results (let's assume that the limiting timespan is 30days)

```
customEvents 
| where timestamp >= ago(30d)
| summarize min(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get just the min of the timestamp just add the "by" clause:

```
customEvents 
| where timestamp >= ago(30d)
| summarize min(timestamp) by user_Id
```

If you want to get the full row, use arg_min() function, for example:

```
customEvents 
| where timestamp >= ago(30d)
| summarize arg_min(timestamp, *) by user_Id
```

Comment: oh arg_min is wicked, thank you! For future reference it would be better to change UserId into user_Id - then both queries will be ready to run. Thanks once again!